# Sum of floating point numbers in a list is off by .00000001

Tags: python, floating-point, sum

I'm writing a python function that gets a list of probabilities (each rounded to 2 decimal points) in case the `sum(list)` is not equal to `1.0` and updates the first element of the list to make the `sum(list) = 1.0`. The Function is below:

```
def round_off_list_to_1(prob_list):
    if len(prob_list) != 0:
        prob_list[0] = round(prob_list[0] + (1.0 - sum(prob_list)), 2)
    assert sum(prob_list) == 1, "Sum of random probabilities not equal to 1.0"
    return prob_list
```

What I don't understand is that for the `list = [.59, .33, .08]` , `sum(list) = .9999999`. The function gets called and the list remains the same and assert fails.

Comment: IMO right assert is `assert round(sum(prob_list), 2) == 1`.

Comment: You need a tolerance: in newer versions of python you can use `isclose`, or just use a check like `math.abs(sum(prob_list)  - 1) < 1e-8`